# The Command.. break; in Java what if.?

Tags: java

What if we have an if statement inside a for loop, would it stop the loop or  the if condition...

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (condition) {
        statement;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The `break` statement has no effect on if statements. It only works on `switch`, `for`, `while` and `do` loops. So in your example the break would terminate the `for` loop.

See [this section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) and [this section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) of the Java tutorial.

Comment: Your answer was the most complete so I just added a couple of links to the relevant sections of the Java tutorial instead of posting a new answer. I hope that is OK.

Answer (score 12):

You can break out of just 'if' statement also, if you wish, it may make sense in such a scenario:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
{
CHECK:
   if(condition)
   {
     statement;
     if (another_condition) break CHECK;
     another_statement;
     if (yet_another_condition) break CHECK;
     another_statement;
   }
}
```

you can also break out of labeled {} statement:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
{
CHECK:       
   {
     statement;
     if (another_condition) break CHECK;
     another_statement;
     if (yet_another_condition) break CHECK;
     another_statement;
   }
}
```

Comment: break checks aren't a great way to deal with tailgating programmers.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question,: the second statement is incorrect; and the second example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer is *almost* right.  if `break` statement be mixed by `label` then it can be used in   `if` statement without needing to be in a loop. The following code is completely valid, compiles and runs.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        label:if(i>2){
            break label;
        }               
    }
}
```

However if we remove the label, it fails to compile.

Comment: This is not correct. The label has to label a loop.

Comment: @EJP go ahead and run it in your IDE. it compiles and runs :).

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. Unbelievable how many people vote from `the herd theory`

Answer (score 3):

It will stop the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The break command inside the IF statement will exit the FOR loop.

Answer (score 3):

a `break` statement (and its companion, 'continue', as well) works on a surrounding loop. An `if`-statement is not a loop. So to answer your question: the `break` in your code example will jump out of the `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Once the condition is met and the statement has successfully been executed (let's assuming no exception is thrown), then the `break` exits from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    jumpIf: if (condition) {
        statement;
        break jumpIf;
    }
}
```